# "Error": "invalid input value for enum" only when using pg package in application to do INSERT SQL operation

Tags: node.js, postgresql, enums, pg, enumerated-types

I am beginning to build out the user authentication part of my application and I am using PostgreSQL as my database. I have a table set up in PG with the following code. This is the code I used to set-up my `USERS` table. When I did `INSERTS` in the `psql` console everything works fine. However, when I do it in my NodeJS application which uses the `pg` npm package and is querying the database via a client instance, does NOT work properly.

```
  DROP EXTENSION IF EXISTS pgcrypto;
  DROP TYPE IF EXISTS genderEnum;
  DROP TYPE IF EXISTS roleEnum;
  -----------------------------------------------

  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trigger_set_timestamp()
  RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
  BEGIN
      NEW.updated_at = NOW();
      RETURN NEW;
      END;
  $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

  -----------------------------------------------
  DROP EXTENSION IF EXISTS pgcrypto;
  CREATE EXTENSION pgcrypto;

  -----------------------------------------------

  CREATE TYPE genderEnum AS ENUM ('male', 'female', 'other');
  CREATE TYPE roleEnum AS ENUM ('banned', 'suspended', 'member', 'admin', 'developer');

  -----------------------------------------------
  CREATE TABLE users
  (
  id            serial       NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  username      varchar(33)  NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  password      varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  date_of_birth date         NOT NULL,
  gender        genderEnum   NOT NULL,
  created_at    timestamptz  NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
  updated_at    timestamptz  NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
  role          roleEnum     NOT NULL DEFAULT 'member',
  description   text,
  image         jsonb,
  friends       jsonb
  );

  -----------------------------------------------
  CREATE TRIGGER set_timestamp
  BEFORE UPDATE ON users
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE trigger_set_timestamp();
```

---

Command Line (successful) Attempts:

```
INSERT INTO USERS ( username, password, date_of_birth, gender, role, description, friends ) VALUES ( 'Amy', '123456', '02/24/1975', 'female', 'member', 'I am a fun girl.', '["Jack", "Suzie"]' );


INSERT 0 1


SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE username = 'Amy';


 id | username | password | date_of_birth | gender |          created_at           |          updated_at           |  role  |   description    | image |      friends
----+----------+----------+---------------+--------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+--------+------------------+-------+-------------------
  9 | Amy      | 123456   | 1975-02-24    | female | 2019-08-17 03:19:34.518501-04 | 2019-08-17 03:19:34.518501-04 | member | I am a fun girl. |       | ["Jack", "Suzie"]
(1 row)
```

---

#### **NodeJS Code (unsuccessful) Attempt**

*Below is my NodeJS code* that I currently have for this query. I have an async/await function wrapped inside of a POST method. I am destructuring the values from `req.body` and then inserting them into the SQL query as parameters in place of the `$1, $2, $3...etc`, and for the **NON**-required values (like `description`, `image`, and `friends`), I have a statement like `friends||null` as a fallback to be precautionary (I'm not 100% sure it's needed). I also have some primitive error handling going on, but that is just there for me to have something atm. I will update that when it the time comes and it is more important for the application.

```
router.post("/register", async (req, res) => {

  const date = new Date();
  const loggableDate = date.toLocaleDateString();
  const loggableTime = date.toLocaleTimeString();

  const { username, password, date_of_birth, gender, role, description, image, friends } = req.body;

  console.log("\nBODY", req.body, "\n");

  try {
    const user = await database.query(`INSERT into 
    USERS (
      username, 
      password, 
      date_of_birth, 
      gender, 
      role, 
      description, 
      image, 
      friends
    ) 
    VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8)`, [
        [username],
        [password],
        [date_of_birth],
        [gender],
        [role],
        [description || null],
        [image || null],
        [friends || null]
      ]
    );

    if (!user) {
      return res.status(404).json({ message: errors.clientSideError404, date: loggableDate, time: loggableTime });
    }

    return res.status(200).json(newUser.rows[0]);

  } catch (error) {

    return res.status(500).json({ error: error.stack, date: loggableDate, time: loggableTime });

  }
});
```

The result of the above NodeJS code:

```
{
    "error": "error: invalid input value for enum genderenum: \"{\"female\"}\"\n    at Connection.parseE (/Users/JON-DOE/Desktop/virtual-desktop/Work/app/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:604:11)\n    at Connection.parseMessage (/Users/JON-DOE/Desktop/virtual-desktop/Work/app/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:401:19)\n    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/JON-DOE/Desktop/virtual-desktop/Work/app/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:121:22)\n    at Socket.emit (events.js:203:13)\n    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:294:12)\n    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:275:11)\n    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:210:10)\n    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:166:17)",
    "date": "8/17/2019",
    "time": "3:44:51 AM"
}
```

When I plug in the following object on PostMan (with raw data button selected, application/JSON set as the text type).

```
{
    "username": "Amy",
    "password": "123456",
    "date_of_birth": "02/24/1957",
    "gender": "female",
    "role": "member",
    "description": "I am a fun girl",
    "friends": ["Jack", "Suzie"]
}
```

I am hoping to figure out what I am doing wrong with this enumerator type. I am thinking it's something to do with the way I'm inputting the data with PostMan because the `psql` console works just fine. Please forgive me if this post is long-winded. I am fairly new to backend programming, so I am taking in a lot of information here, and someone's help will be extremely appreciated. Just for the record, user's passwords will be encrypted with bCryptJS along with JWTs, but for now, I'm just trying to get a simple INSERT to work!!

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your error after unquoting:

```
error: invalid input value for enum genderenum: "{"female"}"
```

It looks like the value you try to insert is not `female` but `{"female"}`. Observe:

```
=> create temporary table test (a genderEnum);
=> insert into test values ('female');
INSERT 0 1
=> insert into test values ('{"female"}')
ERROR:  invalid input value for enum genderenum: "{"female"}"
```

So it looks like your data isn't what you think it is.

Comment: The data seems to be right outside of the query. It's like the query is adding it to a JSON Stringified object. This is the console.log right before it gets to the query. `BODY {
  username: 'Amy',
  password: '123456',
  date_of_birth: '02/24/1957',
  gender: 'female',
  role: 'member',
  description: 'I am a fun girl',
  friends: [ 'Jack', 'Suzie' ]
} `

Comment: I wonder if it is the parameterized input doing that is causing this problem, b/c I can do an INSERT when I inline the SQL variables with a string literal, but that puts my app at risk for a SQL injection, unfortunately :(

Comment: I'd try to create a SSCCE for just connects to the db and performs the insert to see if this works. I'm not a NodeJS developer and it would be hard for me to do.

Comment: I decided to just remove the enum types out of my database because either I'm not working with them correctly with Node, or they don't work as expected in the `pg` gem that I use to setup my config which btw is done like such 

`const { Client } = require("pg");
const client = new Client({
  connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL || process.env.PG_CONNECTION_STRING
});
client.connect(); `.

I am going to assign the column types to `varchar` and programmatically, and validate input programmatically (like `if (validate(gender)) { // continue} else { throw new Error("error message"))`

Comment: You cab get the same database enforcement/validation provided by enum by adding check constraints. For example to validate gender just "alter table users add constraint validate_gender check (gender in ('male', 'female', 'other'));" This will automatically validate and not require you to validate programmatically.

Comment: The inner brackets need to be removed from each of those parameter inputs